VBA filtering OLAP Cube based on list getting "Run-time error '1004' The item could not be found in the OLAP Cube"
I tested the code with a small amount of product codes and it works but when I enter a large amount of product codes I get the

Run-time error '1004'
The item could not be found in the OLAP Cube.

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields( _
        "[Product].[Source Product Number].[Source Product Number]").VisibleItemsList _
        = ProductCodes

I imagine this means product codes in my list do not exist in the data base and throws this error. I aware of the on error resume next but the error happens at this point and I dont see how I can place that in the VisibleItemsList:
Sub OLAPfilterLIST()

'Set references up-front
Dim wksData1 As Worksheet
Dim wksData2 As Worksheet

    Set wksData1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set wksData2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    
    
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim i As Long
        i = 1
             
        ReDim ProductCodes(1 To LastRow) As String
        Dim A As Range
        For Each A In .Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
            If Not IsEmpty(A) Then
                ProductCodes(i) = "[Product].[Source Product Number].&[" & A.Value & "]"
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next A
    End With

wksData1.Activate

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields( _
        "[Product].[Source Product Number].[Source Product Number]").VisibleItemsList _
        = ProductCodes

End Sub

I did try playing around with the on error but having not luck and not finding much online thats specific to my problem
